# Are there security/performance issues if I connect a dockerized web app to an Amazon RDS DB?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker

I'm developing an app in Django. During the development process, I've used an Amazon RDS PostgreSQL DB (using a free Dev/Test template). The database configuration for the app is straightforward:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
        'HOST': 'AWS_endpoint',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

I've decided to create a docker image and use Amazon ECS to deploy the app.

When I run the app as a docker container, it works just fine with the current database configurations; however, I've not seen any tutorials that discuss this solution to deploying a docker container and a database (i.e. creating an image of the app and using a hosted db solution - in this case AWS RDS PSQL). As an aside, most of the tutorials show the image being constructed with both the database and Django site on the same image, but that seems like a bad idea.

**My question:** In a production environment, is it acceptable for me to connect my docker container (Django) to my database (Amazon RDS PostgreSQL) in the manner I've described above, only using a new production db instance?

At this point, I'm convinced that the answer to my question is obviously stupid (i.e., "of course, why would you ask such a thing?" or "absolutely not, why would you ask such a thing?"), because I can't find an answer anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean RDS PostgreSQL or Aurora PostgreSQL, or you are self-hosting the db on ecs?

Comment: I've edited the question to specify RDS - thanks.

Comment: You already answered your question: "of course you can".

Comment: Yes, it is acceptable, even maybe entirely recommended. But it is also strongly recommended to use AWS Secrets Manager, not a clear text password inside your container.

Answer (score 0):

Use a three tier architecture.

1. Publid subnet: Load balancer
2. Private subnet: ECS cluster
3. Restrcted subnet: No routes to NAT Gateway. Access possible only from ECS cluster via a security group.

https://github.com/aws-samples/vpc-multi-tier

Remove DB password. Store it in AWS Secrets manager. Inject it at runtime dynamically.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-data-security-container-task/